# Why is this undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute()?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to parse comments from facebook page. I have stored data in `$graphObject` but it does not parse data through it and returns following errors

> Notice: Undefined variable: session in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\index.php on line 92
>
> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Facebook\FacebookRequest::execute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\facebook\index.php on line 97

**Here is the code**

```
  require_once __DIR__ . '/path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/FacebookApp.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/FacebookBatchRequest.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/FacebookClient.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/SignedRequest.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/Authentication/AccessToken.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/Facebook.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphUser.php');
include('path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/src/Facebook/GraphNodes/GraphObject.php');
 use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\Facebook;

$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/{page_id}_{post_id}/comments'
);

$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

I am unaware about which library is needed here. Kindly help

Comment: You are trying to use code that was written for the PHP SDK v4 with the current v5 version. Go check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted to see how the current one works, it has lots of examples.

Comment: Can you provide the code for php versioin v4

Comment: Why? You are embedding the v5 version of the SDK already.

Comment: then whats the main problem?

Comment: That you are using code that was written for the SDK v4 ...

Comment: Do I need code of SDK v5?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use the SDK v5, you need code that matches the objects and methods it provides.

Comment: Ok sure.. But facebook provides me SDK v4. From Where to get v5?

Comment: So you just named the folder you put the SDK in `/path/to/php-graph-sdk-5.0.0/` for fun? Again: You are already using the SDK v5. Now all you gotta do is go and look at some of the basic examples in the documentation ...